# Shuffle with Fisher–Yates

Tags: vb.net

I am having a problem with my program, I am trying to shuffle a bunch of picture boxes and then unshuffle them I have tried the Fisher–Yates shuffle with no luck. please show me an example.

I am using a standard form with a panel on it, A picturebox, textbox and three buttons.

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
Private Sub TestSplit()
    Dim fr_bm As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
    Dim wid As Integer = PictureBox1.Image.Width \ 8
    Dim hgt As Integer = PictureBox1.Image.Height \ 6
    Dim colnum, rownum As Integer
    For rownum = 0 To 5
        For colnum = 0 To 7
            Dim to_bm As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
            Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(to_bm)
            Dim fr_rect As New Rectangle(colnum * wid, rownum * hgt, hgt, hgt)
            Dim to_rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, wid, hgt)
            gr.DrawImage(fr_bm, to_rect, fr_rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
            Dim MyPictureBox As New PictureBox
            MyPictureBox.Height = hgt
            MyPictureBox.Width = wid
            MyPictureBox.Left = colnum * hgt
            MyPictureBox.Top = rownum * wid
            MyPictureBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
            'MyPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal
            MyPictureBox.Image = to_bm
            MyPictureBox.Name = "PicBox" & rownum & colnum
            Panel1.Controls.Add(MyPictureBox)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub OpenButt_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenButt.Click
    Using O As New OpenFileDialog With {.Filter = "(Image Files)|*.jpg;*.png;*.bmp;*.gif;*.ico|Jpg, | *.jpg|Png, | *.png|Bmp, | *.bmp|Gif, | *.gif|Ico | *.ico", .Multiselect = False, .Title = "Select image"}
        If O.ShowDialog = 1 Then
            TextBox1.Text = O.FileName
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(O.FileName)
            PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        Else
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If

    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub BoardButt_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BoardButt.Click
    TestSplit()
End Sub

Private Sub ShuffleButt_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ShuffleButt.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why tag this as C# when it's clearly written in VB.NET?

Comment: You said you tried Fisher-Yates with no luck. Where is the code you tried, and what was wrong with the result?

Comment: What do you mean with *"unshuffling them"*?

Answer (score 0):

Drop 2 Listboxes on a form and a button (in the middle is best)

Listbox1 on the left is the ORIGINAL SORTED list
Listbox2 on the right is a COPY of the original sorted list

Click the button and the files in the listbox2 are shuffled

The code is below

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    '
    ListBox2.Items(0) = ListBox1.Items(0)
    For i = 1 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        j = Int(Rnd(1) * i)
        ListBox2.Items(i) = ListBox2.Items(j)
        ListBox2.Items(j) = ListBox1.Items(i)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim counta As Integer
    '
    For counta = 0 To 39
        ListBox1.Items.Add("image" & counta & ".gif")
        ListBox2.Items.Add("image" & counta & ".gif")
    Next
    counta = Nothing

End Sub
```

Reference: Inside Out Shuffle
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle